# Find Average of Three Random Numbers Sampled from a Pre-Defined List in Excel

Tags: excel, average, random

I have tried to Google this, but I could not find anything even approaching a solution.

Suppose I have a list of ten different ages. I want to randomly sample three ages from the list of ten across 200 trials, indicating the three that were chosen by making the color of the text red for each, and then calculating the average of those three and displaying it in a cell to the right of the last number in the series.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
                                                              Average

Trial 1:  **40**, 31, 18, **6**, 10, **22**, 58, 92, 34, 77    22.6  
Trial 2:  40, 31, **18**, 6, 10, 22, **58**, 92, 34, **77**    51.0  
Trial 3:  40, **31**, 18, 6, **10**, 22, 58, **92**, 34, 77    44.3  
.  
.  
.
```

How do I accomplish this in Excel?

Comment: are all those number in one cell or are they each in their own column?

Comment: are the sampled ages unique or can they be repeated?  can you randomly same say 40 two or three times instead of just once?

Comment: @ForwardEd   Each is in their own column, and they can be repeated from one trial to another (though I prefer for there to be some distance between repetitions, if possible) but not within a single trial.

Comment: @ForwardEd  No, the numbers have to be unique, and in the defined set, within a single trial

Comment: ok look at these functions, RAND, RANDBETWEEN, IF.  And then look at Excel's Conditional formatting.  I am working with those currently in formulas.  This would be probably much better in VBA.  the problem with RAND in a formula is that is chooses a new number every time a cell changes.

Comment: @ForwardEd  Can you provide an example formula or VBA script?

Comment: are the ages listed in each trial always the same age? IF yes, OldUgly has a cleaner layout. Otherwise OlUgly will work for you with a slight modification to some of the formulas.

Comment: @ForwardEd Yes, the ages listed in each trial remain the same from one trial to the next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this with helper cells which you can hide.  This image shows the results and you can hide columns O to T.

[image: Example results]

In column O to Q I placed the random function with one less to the range since you need unique samples.  This is the same as pull 1 ball from a bag of ten ball numbered 1-10.  After each pull, there is one less ball in the bag.  The formulas are as follows:

```
=randbetween(1,10)
=randbetween(1,9)
=randbetween(1,8)
```

Since we cant use a statement like

```
=IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,9)=O2,O2+1,RANDBETWEEN(1,9)
```

because the second randbetween generates a new number is not subject to the IF check We need to do the +1 or +2 in a separate cell.  Therefore I used R to T to do this with R really just being a place holder as it is the same value as O.  The formulas are as follows:

```
=O2
=IF(P2=O2,P2+1,P2)
=IF(OR(AND(Q2>O2+1,Q2>P2+1),AND(Q2<O2,Q2<P2),OR(AND(Q2=O2+1,Q2=P2-1),AND(Q2=O2-1,Q2=P2+1))),0,IF(OR(AND(Q2=O2,Q2=P2),Q2+1=O2,Q2+1=P2),2,IF(OR(Q2=O2,Q2=P2,O2=P2),1,0)))
```

We now have a list of three unique number from 1 to 10

now we use these picks in our average formula with an offset as follows in cell M2:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($A2,0,R2,1,1),OFFSET($A2,0,S2,1,1),OFFSET($A2,0,T2,1,1))
```

And finally we need to add the colour to numbers with conditional formatting, so we select B2:K201 and place the following formula in our conditional formatting and colour as required.

```
=OR(COLUMN(B2)-1=$R2,COLUMN(B2)-1=$S2,COLUMN(B2)-1=$T2)
```

Now if you do not want this to recalculate every time a cell changes then set your page calculation to MANUAL instead of AUTOMATIC.

In order to hide columns O to T simply select all three column letter, right click and select hide column.

### UPDATE

The third IF equation was updated as it was previously not working right.

Comment: I was using rows 6-10 to test special cases to ensure unique numbers from the IF statement

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was after.

Comment: There is an error with the long if statement.  I am working on it right now.  Its failing in the case of the three random numbers being 1, 1, 3  Its making the last number 4 when it does not need to.

Comment: its also failing at 2, 2, 1 where its making the last number 3 and it does not need to do anything to the number. same as 1, 3, 2.

Comment: @user913304 OK, the third if statement is working as intended now.  Apologies for not realizing it had an error in it when I posted it.  I will try and be more rigorous with testing in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

[image]

As typical examples, cells A3:C3 contain the following array formula:`{=randint(1,10)}`. To enter an array formula, select the three cells, type in the formula (without the braces "{}"), then hit Shift+Ctl+Enter. This can be copy/filled down.

See this for RandInt vba code: http://mcgimpsey.com/excel/udfs/randint.html. Note that using RANDBETWEEN cannot guarantee three unique numbers. There are spreadsheet methods to get the three numbers, but they are more complex than using VBA.

Cell E3 contains: `=IF(OR($A3=E$1,$B3=E$1,$C3=E$1),E$2,"")`. This can be filled to the right and filled down.

Cell O3 contains: `=AVERAGE(E3:N3)`

Conditional formatting is used for the yellow highlights.

I recommend setting your options for manual calculation.

Comment: did you actually randomly get no repeats in columns A:C with your RANDBETWEEN? or did you do something in there to ensure the uniqueness of the number picked?

Comment: I did not use RANDBETWEEN. I used a user defined function RandInt as found on mcgimpsey.com